# Rotating torch.Tensor 3D matrix from front view to top view

Tags: python, math, matrix, pytorch, scipy

I have a 3D cube in `torch`, something like this:

```py
import torch

square = torch.as_tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
cube = square.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1, 1, 3)
```

Now, the cubes are actually quite big, so conversions to/from `cpu` for `numpy` are expensive.

How can I rotate the cube 90° about any axis (x, y, or z), without using `numpy`/`scipy`?

---

For reference, here's an implementation that does use `scipy`:

```py
import scipy
import torch

def rotate(
    volume: torch.Tensor,
    angle: float,
    axes: tuple[int, int] = (1, 0),
    **rotate_kwargs,
) -> torch.Tensor:
    """Wrap scipy.ndimage.rotate for rotating a cube."""
    orig_device = volume.device
    return torch.as_tensor(
        scipy.ndimage.rotate(volume.cpu(), angle, axes, **rotate_kwargs),
        device=orig_device,
    )
```

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.rot90.html ?